# How to send non-string objects into pipeline with ExecuteApplicationPipeline preparer

Tags: intershop

I am trying to create a dbmigrate file which will call a ExecuteApplicationPipeline preparer, but one of the mandatory parameters is a ChannelRepository as on screenshot, is there any way to fullfil that parameter through dbmigrate file?

I have also tried leaving out that parameter but it doesn't work.

[image: dbmigrate file and target pipeline]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code of `ExecuteApplicationPipeline` or `ExecutePipeline` reveals that all parameters need to be of type `String`. After all you're configuring it via properties file

```
    protected Domain site;
    protected Application application;
    protected String pipelineName;
    protected String startNodeName;
    protected Hashtable<String, String> pipelineParameters = new Hashtable<>();
```

You can create a pipeline of your own that translates a domain name (e.g. YOUR_ORG-YOUR_CHANNEL) into a repository and executes the call against `ProcessApplication-Create`. See for example [image]